# Stopping Table Row height from changing when hover over icon that uses transition

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has several icons in it and when the user hovers over them the icon size is changed slightly using transform. However this causes buggy behavior in that the table rows bounce and the user moves from one icon to the next. Is there a way to keep the table row height from changing on hover? Below is the CSS that handles the hover:

```
  .IconHover:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        transform: scale(1.1);
        opacity: 1.0;
        width: 32px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

And this is an example that shows the behavior:

```
    <table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="customTR">
            <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-F99fDKhNzQw/UCbi0AvmOCI/AAAAAAAAAds/DYettY3Mi70/s1600/email_button.jpg" class="IconHover" width="30" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I created a [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ku2DZ/) JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem. When users over over any TR Icon that row should not change its height but rather just the ICON.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to increase the height of the td, try putting it `40px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make the height of the `<tr>` tag larger than 1.1 * the height of the object to be transformed by doing something like this: `<tr style = "height: 50px;">`. This solves the problem in your fiddle, and I hope you can use this concept to fix the rest of your table cells. The problem originates from the image rescaling. Because you do not have a set width/height on your tags, the cells remain as small as possible until they need to grow. By pre-setting the size, you can avoid the annoying resizing on the hover event. You may also run into the same problem with `<td>` tags, in which case, you will have to adjust the width of the cell. Just remember that you cannot set the width of a `<tr>` tag, and you have to set the width of the actual cell.

Comment: thanks much. I thought that was all it was but wasn't sure if (1) that was the root of the issue and (2) if it was the correct way to fix it.